# Do fancy box images in links load if not clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, fancybox

I use [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) on a site to show secondary images if wanted by the user. The images in question reside inside fancybox links, like so:

```
<a class="fancybox" title="Click to see more detail" href="media/more-detailed-image.jpg"><img src="media/image-name.jpg" alt="etc"></a>
```

Do browsers load the fancybox images even if they're not clicked by the user?

Comment: The reference to an external content (image, html page, pdf document, etc.) set in the `href` attribute of your anchor (`<a>` tag) will never be loaded by the browser, it's just a reference. The only exception though is inline content that is referred by the ID of a section in your document like `href="#inlinecontentid"`. This is valid regardless whether you are using fancybox or not. Bear in mind that images within the `src` attribute of the `<img/>` tag are always loaded by the browser despite they are visible or not.

Comment: Good explanation, thanks. I'd mark it as a solution but seeing as it's in a comment I can't do that.

Answer (score -1):

No.
AFAIK fancy box and similar scripts set the css `display` property to `none` which in turns prevents that element from being rendered.

So images are not fetched by the browser unless they become visible.

Refer to [this article](http://alistapart.com/article/now-you-see-me) please.

Comment: Browsers will load content even if the css for that content declares "display:none;"